# Missing space when hovering over tag score on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, tooltips

A little pedantic, but once I noticed it I couldn't unsee it.

When I hover over the tag score for a user who has asked and answered a question in the tag on Meta, there is no space after the first period.

For example, if I hover over my score for the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, I get this:

> [image: Example from my profile]

<del>I also tried an example on the main site, hovering over Jon Skeet's tag score for generics. Sure enough, the space was there. (I haven't asked a question on the main site, so couldn't use my own profile.)</del>

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by @MichaelLiu on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207683/cosmetic-bug-in-tag-answer-votes-tool-tip) question, the space is now missing on the main site too. Here's his image:

> [image: No space here either]

Can we add the spaces back?

Comment: @hims056 Thanks for adding the red circle. :)

Comment: The space *is* there, it's just small.

Comment: @Undo - [I don't think so](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qolgC.png).

Comment: @hims056 Relax, he's just joking since there's definitely pixels in between. (Of course, I still want an actual space character there.)

Comment: I bet it's localisation.

Comment: So why this is still open?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will be fixed as of revision `2014.1.28.1902` on MSO and `2014.1.28.1335` elsewhere. Give or take.

Comment: Just saw it. Thanks!