# Cosmetic bug in tag "answer votes" tool tip

Tags: bug, profile-page, tooltips

On the **tags** tab of my user profile, the `title` of the `answer-votes` element is missing a space (or a line break) after the first sentence when there are two sentences:

[image: Screenshot of answer votes tool tip]

Comment: Interesting. When I posted the other question, the issue hadn't surfaced on the main site yet. I'll update the other question to reflect this development. Is it okay if I link back to this question and use this image?

Comment: @DennisMeng: Sure.